# What is wrong with this class/instance?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I have this:

```
data Vector3 t = Vector3 { ax, ay, az :: t }
data Point3 t = Point3 { x, y, z :: t }
data Ray3 t = Ray3 { ori :: Point3 t, dir :: Vector3 t }
data Sphere t = Sphere { center :: Point3 t, radius :: t }
```

I want a Shape type class, so I did this:

```
class Shape s where
      distance :: s -> Ray3 t -> t
```

`distance` takes a shape and a ray and computes the distance to the shape along the given ray.  When I try to create an instance, it doesn't work.  This is what I have so far:

```
instance Shape (Sphere t) where
         distance (Sphere center radius) ray = -- some value of type t --
```

How do I create an instance of Shape?  I've tried everything I can think of, and I'm getting all kind of errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the type variable `t` in `Sphere t` is not the same as the one in the type signature of `distance`. Your current types are saying that if I have a `Sphere t1`, I can check it against a `Ray3 t2`. However, you probably want these to be the same type. To solve this, I would change the `Shape` class to

```
class Shape s where
    distance :: s t -> Ray3 t -> t
```

Now the dependency on `t` is explicit, so if you write your instance as

```
instance Shape Sphere where
    distance (Sphere center radius) ray = ...
```

the types should line up nicely, although you'll probably need to add in some numeric constraints on `t` to do any useful calculations.

Comment: Why is it `instance Shape Sphere where...` and not `instance Shape (Sphere t) where...`???

Comment: @t61p Because the new typeclass wants an argument of *kind* `* -> *` - a type taking one argument. Thus we must not provide an explicit argument.